# PHP_SELF & Javascript setAttribute

Tags: javascript, php, setattribute

I have the following code in PHP:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <?php $value = $_POST['Field1'] ?>
    <input type="text" id="Field1" name="Field1" value="<?php echo $value ?>">
    <input type="button" value="ButtonValue" onclick="SubmitFunction()">
</form>
```

And some function in JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function SubmitFunction(){
        //... do some stuff here
        //But here I need to assign value to Field1:
        document.getElementById("Field1").setAttribute("value", "Some value");
        document.form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

When this code loads for the first time, it says there is undefined index Field1. It's absolutely right.

But when I set attribute value to this field using SubmitFunction(), page reloads and it still can't find Field1 ! This is my problem.

I noticed that in pure HTML code the initial form looks like:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="Field1" name="Field1" value>
    <input type="button" value="ButtonValue" onclick="SubmitFunction()">
</form>
```

Where is my problem (except brain)?

Comment: what's your browser i test it in FF26 working

Comment: Mine is Google Chrome 32

Comment: AAAAHm... sorry I suck. In my last useless answer (i delete it) I told you how to prevent submit. But you nedd to fire it... my bad. However... I have paste your code locally and it works fine. Only one thing to submit the form I've need to change your `document.form.submit();` in `document.forms[0].submit();` but when the page reloads I find "Some value" like value.

Comment: Yes, it works this way. But I found another issue.

setAttribute("value", "Some value") sets value which is obtained with AJAX callback function. It simply returns this value. Nothing more. If in my project I simply submit form without filling this value, it works as expected. But if I set value through setAttribute - is fails.

Well, I probably need to check my code and find this misbehaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
        function SubmitFunction(){
            //... do some stuff here
            //But here I need to assign value to Field1:
        document.getElementById("Field1").setAttribute("value", "Some value");
        document.form.submit(document.getElementById("Field1").getAttribute("value"));
        }
    </script>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <?php $value = $_POST['Field1'] ?>
        <input type="text" id="Field1" name="Field1" value="<?php echo $value?$value:''; ?>">
        <input type="button" value="ButtonValue" onclick="SubmitFunction()">
    </form>
```

Comment: document.form.submit(document.getElementById("Field1").getAttribute("value"));
What if there is a plenty of fields I need to submit? Should I handle them all like this?

Comment: there is a function of jquery named serialize() which will return all element of the form. You have to just use the function and send serialize data to the server